# deflate/compress javascript and css files

Tags: apache, gzip

After adding this to the virtual host for a domain

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/javascript text/css
```

The response header doesn't contain any content-type: gzip or deflate

This is the response header for a CSS file

```
Cache-Control max-age=29030400
Connection Keep-Alive
Date Sat, 06 Jun 2015 10:15:35 GMT
Etag "f0007e-46364-514a70ecd9000"
Expires Sat, 07 May 2016 10:15:35 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=97
Server Apache
Vary Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: How do you read these HTTP headers? Using which program/utility?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

and remember to clear cache before reloading the page.

Comment: Or pressing Ctrl+F5 to hard fetch all resources.

Answer (score 0):

Hook your browser to Fiddler and see whats is happening. CSS files might have been cached in your browser in which case it will loaded from the browser cache after checking expiry. You should see responses with status codes 304. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Also make sure your VH configuration is something like below

```
<VirtualHost *:PORT>
    LoadModule deflate_module "<SO_LOCATION>/mod_deflate.so"
    <IfModule deflate_module>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript text/css application/javascript text/j-son text/javascript
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache 2.4 Documentation located at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

Make sure in your httpd.conf you have mod_deflate loaded.

What you want to use is the first sample config in the doc (adding/removing mime types per your own requirements):

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript